# Why all folders not included in IPMRootFolder using Redemption?

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I know this wasn't an issue before but suddenly when i look at the folders that are under the RDOPstStore or RDOStore IPMRootFolder now i only get the standard folder names of Inbox, Deleted Items, Outbox, and Sent.

There is an additional custom named folder called "whalley-g" that i need to recursively iterate through.

This was working fine at one point for a year, but now i only get the four folders.

```
Redemption.RDOSession mySession = new Redemption.RDOSession();

Redemption.RDOPstStore pst = mySession.LogonPstStore(pstToProcess.PSTFullPathAndName, 1, "Outlook", 1, 1);

int numFolders = pst.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Count;
```

numFolders should be 5 but is only 4.  I didn't bother with the recursive code since i just need to get by the fact that it isn't including the custom folder at all.

[image]

Comment: Just to head off the inevitable comment, no i have no control over the folder organization. It is how they are organized when we receive them, and must be able to handle as is.

Comment: Are you sure the PST fie actually has that folder? If you copy that folder to another machine and open it, can you see the folder? Keep in mind that if the PST fiel was not properly closed, the MSPST provider will "fix" the store when it is opened.

Comment: I have tried multiple PST with similar organization. Again, this worked for a year just fine. I did switch to using the 32 bit version of Redemption, but that shouldn't make a difference.  Right? Will try on another pst. These are the Enron data-set PSTs.

Comment: Yes, that should not make a difference. But make sure the PST files are properly closed. Where are they modified?

Comment: That's the thing, we don't modify them. We only read them using our redemption code. Since this happened i used a OST PST viewer to just make sure the structures is the same.  Again, i only looked at a couple with the viewer. We have run with 6 different PSTs from the collection.

Comment: Would switching from 64 bit Office on the machine down to 32 bit make a difference? Just reaching.

Comment: No, that won't make a difference. So if you open the same PST file on the same machine where your code is running, you can see that folder just fine?

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the same file? Is pstToProcess.PSTFullPathAndName a fully qualified file name?

Comment: Yes sir, to all questions. It is so weird. I can put them on a Dropbox folder if you want to take a look? I am using the interop.redemption dll, does that matter?

Comment: Sure, send me a link to dmitry (at) dimastr (dot) com.

Comment: I did switch it so it is just using redemption.dll now, and same results.